# Show that $P(-X) = (-1)^nP(X)$ using $Q(X) = P(-X)$ knowing that $Q, P \in \text{Ker} \Phi$

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces

Let be $\Phi$ the following mapping :

$P \mapsto (X^2 - 1)P'' + 2XP' - n(n + 1)P$ from $\mathbb{R}_n[X] \to \mathbb{R}_n[X]$

We know that $\dim \text{Ker } \Phi = 1$.
By taking $P$ such that $\text{Ker } \Phi = \text{Vect}(P)$ (the smallest vector space created by all the linear combinations of $P$).

I am trying to prove that $P(-X) = (-1)^n P(X)$, using $Q(X) = P(-X)$ and $\Phi(Q)$.

What I tried:

- To establish a relation between coefficients, it worked, but it seemed too much complicated to me. (writing polynomial as a sum, applying the function, etc...)
- Using partial fractions with the relation : $P = \lambda Q$ for some $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is sufficient to consider the coefficient in the highest degree of the both polynomials, let them be $a_n$ and $b_n$.

It's obvious that $b_n = (-1)^n a_n$.

Using $P = \lambda Q$, we have $a_n = (-1)^n b_n$.

Then, $\lambda = (-1)^n$.